# Combining two dataframes so that the values in one dataframe become headers in the other

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My first data frame d1 is something like this.

```
    num value
0   1   229
1   2   203
2   3   244
```

The second one, d2:

```
    num person  cash
0   1   person1 29
1   1   person2 81
2   2   person1 17
3   2   person2 75
4   3   person1 62
5   3   person3 55
```

And I would like to combine them based on `num` in a way that inputs of `person` become headers of new columns in d1. And the new columns are filled with the values `cash` from d2.

```
    num value person1 person2 person 3
0   1   229   29      81      0
1   2   203   17      75      0
2   3   244   62      0       55
```

Is it some kind of combination between `merge()` and `unstack()`? The example seems trivial, most likely I was not able to describe it sufficiently well when googling the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try pivot `df2` and merge:

```
df1.merge(df2.pivot('num','person','cash'),
          on='num')
```

Output:

```
   num  value  person1  person2
0    1    229       29       81
1    2    203       17       75
2    3    244       62       55
```

---

**Edit**: For the updated data, same idea but use `set_index().unstack()` instead of `pivot`. This helps fill the missing values with `0` easier.

```
df1.merge(df2.set_index(['num','person'])['cash']
              .unstack(fill_value=0),
          on='num')
```

Output:

```
   num  value  person1  person2  person3
0    1    229       29       81        0
1    2    203       17       75        0
2    3    244       62        0       55
```